# MSBuild how to create a web deploy package for .NET Core apps without producing zip file

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

So what I'm trying to do is build a .NET Core app with MSBuild, and have it create the web deploy folder but without automatically putting it in a zip file. I can do this for .NET Framework apps by using `/p:WebPublishMethod=Package` and `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=false`, it creates the same folder structure but without adding it to a zip file. However with a .NET Core app, it seems to ignore this flag and always zips up the final package.

The reason I do not want it zipped up is I need to add a number of "custom" files to the build before I can deploy it. I can't add the files during the build itself because we have a number of different clients, and they all share the same "base" software, and then the client specific files need to be added afterwords. So I want to build the "base" software, then be able to copy the output folder, add the client specific files, and then zip up that build to be deployed to IIS. This saves a tremendous amount of time because the alternative is doing a new build for each client, even though 95% of the software is the same.

So is there a different way to accomplish this with .NET Core apps?

I've been testing with MSBuild via command line. The solution has a mix of .NET Framework and .NET Core asp.net websites. This is what i'm running:

```
msbuild.exe "Solution.sln" /nologo /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PreBuildEvent="" /p:PostBuildEvent=""  /p:BasePackageLocation="C:\Temp\BuildOutput" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release"
```

This works for the .NET Framework websites, but the .NET Core websites continue to be zipped up

And just a note that the BasePackageLocation is a custom property that sets the PackageLocation to "$(BasePackageLocation)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\" so that each website is put in its own sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a different way to accomplish this with .NET Core apps?

Sorry but the answer could be negative. This is [one issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/729491/visual-studio-build-task-for-aspnet-core-30-with-m.html) about publishing `.net core` projects, it has been reported to Product Team, there might be a long way to go before the fix.

For `web deploy package` mode in `.net core`, you'll get `WebApplication.deploy.cmd` in the same folder where the `.zip` exists, many commands in the `xx.cmd` are associated with the `xx.zip`, so it's not recommended to manually do something to `unzip` it.

I suggest we can track the issue there(DC) and I will update the answer if there's any update or fix :)